# Providing Backwards Compatability with Python 3.6 Variable Annotations

Tags: python, python-3.6, backwards-compatibility, typechecking

I am trying to create a python package (not anywhere at the moment) and I want to use 3.6 python variable annotations, that is

```
foo: int = 5
```

while still providing support for Python 3.5.

Is there any way to provide these style of variable annotations inside Python 3.5, either through a

```
from __future__ import variable_annotations
```

or similar. I know it is possible to use comment type annotations, but I would like to be able to use this style.

Comment: [PEP 526 Syntax for Variable Annotations ](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#backwards-compatibility) says it is backwards compatible, but I can't find any examples on how to make it so. I've got a codebase developed against 3.6 which I now need to run on 3.5 and I don't want to go and convert all the annotations.

Comment: @RianSanderson That's saying that it's backwards compatible in the sense that code that works in 3.5 pre-PEP526 will still work post-PEP526.

Comment: I suppose it would also be much like [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/5xswh9/can_you_import_fstrings_in_python_35/), in that it is part of the interpreter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TLDR**: No, you can not use variable annotations in Python 3.5 and earlier.

First, [Python 3.6.0 changelog](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-360/) reports variable annotations to be a new feature comparing to 3.5.

Second, [PEP 526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526) is defined as [backward compatible](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#backwards-compatibility). According to [PEP 387](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0387/#backwards-compatibility-rules):

> Unless it is going through the deprecation process below, the behavior
>   of an API must not change between any two consecutive releases.

And this includes:

> Syntax and behavior of these constructs as defined by the reference
>   manual

So PEP 526's  "[fully backwards compatible](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#backwards-compatibility)" just means that Python 3.5 (or to be scrupulous, pre-PEP526) syntax will be working in 3.6.0 without changes: variable annotations [are not mandatory](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#non-goals).

At last, you mentioned "comment type annotations". So I will just give a link to [PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/), which is available for Python 3.5 (it might be useful for some readers of this question).

Comment: Is the best course of action to not use this at all, or to only support 3.6 and up ?

Comment: It really depends on the audience of your package. If significant part of your users has Python 3.5 and below - you have no choice.

Comment: I'm developing a package at the moment, I am wondering if I should support py 3.5 or below.